# Best measure of inter coder reliability for single coded qualitative data

Tags: descriptive-statistics, reliability, agreement-statistics

I have a table of coded strategies, coded by 3 coders, to determine inter-coder reliability. Coders code by placing a 1 where they believe a strategy fulfills a certain amount of criteria.

[image: Coding table with strategy and criteria]

Green represents a cell where all coders were in agreement, and placed a one. White represents a cell where no coder placed a 1. All other colors represent a cell where one or two coders placed a 1. What is the best measure of inter-coder reliability across 3 coders for this kind of qualitative coding?

Comment: This article might help, it's a tutorial for interrater reliability: https://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol08-1/p023/p023.pdf

Comment: Definitely helped @PatrickCoulombe thank you